# Question put on-hold unfairly

Tags: support

I asked a question about licensing on SO, and it was put on hold because it had to do with legal advice. I simply wanted to know if the licenses were compatible with each other, and while it is technically about legal advice, so are most of the questions about licensing. I'd ask for more than one person to look over the question, and if it is off topic expand on why it is instead of giving me a one-sentence answer. Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750523/apache-bsd-and-lgplv2-license-compatibility

Comment: Why are you asking legal advice from programmers?  That's not our field.

Comment: *Some* licensing questions are on-topic on Programmers.SE, but not here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Note that questions about software licenses are on-topic, but legal assistance is not. Tread **very** carefully

Comment: Your question is way to vague to even begin being suitable for any Stack Exchange site. You need to clarify exactly what problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: That tag does have a tag wiki excerpt that explains its use: *"This tag should be used for questions about software that provides licensing services, such as a licensing server or client. Don't use this tag to ask for legal advice about licensing."*

Answer (score 8):

Your question was put on hold not just by ordinary community members, but by a moderator - and for very good reason.

StackOverflow is definitely not the place for legal advice. We write code - we don't take it to court or do any of the sort of stuff you're asking about.

If you need legal advice or a "second opinion" as you say, consult a lawyer in person.

Comment: So, you're telling me that every time you write code and release it under a license, that you pay a lawyer to tell you what license to use? Makes sense.

Comment: I may, or may not use the services of a lawyer.  What I would not do is give any kind of legal advice since I am not qualified to do so.  Giving such advice would be illegal in many jurisdictions.

Comment: It's amusing how people say they don't want to give legal advice, and then proceed to give legal advice by proclaiming that giving legal advice is illegal.

Comment: lol - I did not give advice.  I commented on a Q&A site.

Comment: Saying "I'm not going to do something I believe to be illegal" isn't giving legal advice, @Ben.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look in this [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) link here are the topics that you should actually ask,

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software
  development

As said by Andrew in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750523/apache-bsd-and-lgplv2-license-compatibility) your question was about a legal advice and that question simply did not fit in the above criteria.